# Data Scraping RPA - UiPath

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio

I'm trying to scrape data in UiPath Studio, but not the regular single/multiple page data scraping. I want to scrape the data of every single element.

**E.g:** If I search *Iphone* on Amazon it will give tons of records. What I want is to enter in each record and scrape the data (including the images), then return to the main search page and enter on the second record and do the same thing and finally save all the info in a `.csv` file. Is that possible?

Comment: That's a very broad question, and we don't know what you've tried so far, where you succeeded, and what didn't work as expected. A very similar scenario is covered in their RPA Developer Foundation Training. I suggest starting there, and come back with a specific question if you encounter any difficulties.

Comment: Just as a quick heads up - you won't be saving images into a `csv` file with any usefulness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is possible but it will be a bit complex process you have to use record > web Recording > Copy > CopyText or ScrapeData... and you need to know more about the selectors

take a look at https://academy.uipath.com

- developer training - Level 1 - Foundation Training
- Lesson 4 - Recording
- Lesson 5 - Advanced UI Interaction
- Lesson 6 - Selectors - there is a video of a similar case